# Difference starting a VB.Net application by F5 or by the .exe

Tags: vb.net

If in the ApplicationEvents.vb class I write this simple code:

> Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(ByVal..........) Handles Me.Startup            MessageBox.Show(My.Settings.xxx)

If I run the application by "F5" key I obtain the **REAL** last saved value of xxx (changed at will).

If I run the application **directly** by a click on the .exe file... I obtain the **DEFAULT** value of xxx (that is the value set in Project/Properties/Settings).

Why???

Comment: Settings are saved in a directory name whose name is a hash of properties of your exe file.  Like its name, version, the directory it is stored in.  The name is not the same when you use F5.  Make it the same with Projects > Properties > Debug > scroll down and untick "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process".  And of course keep in mind that this is also going to happen when you deploy your app on the user's machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when debugging it will load the settings for the `yourApp.vshost.exe` application (the currently running process), while when you are running your app it will load the settings for `yourApp.exe`

`vshost` is the *Visual Studio Hosting Process*. It can be disabled (if you want) by following these steps:

1. Right-click your project in the *Solution Explorer* and click `Properties`.
2. Go to the `Debug` tab.
3. Uncheck the `Enable the Visual Studio hosting process` check box.

**You can read more about `vshost` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242202.aspx**

Comment: Soooo simple! Ty mate! :)

Comment: @ezio : No problem. If this answered your question, please mark my post as the accepted answer by pressing the check mark on its left.